# Discord.py: NameError: name 'intents' is not defined

Tags: python, android-intent, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to use intents in my bot but when running the following code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intent=intents)
```

I get the error:

```
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Intents'
```

I am running Python 3.8.2, and I don't know why this is happening. Any help would be appriceated (:

Comment: Which version of discord.py do you have installed?

Comment: Pretty sure it is 3.8.2, if that's incorrect/not possible, how do I check on repl.it? As that is what I'm using to host the bot.

Comment: How did you install discord.py?  3.8.2 is the version of Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely not actually using discord.py 1.5.1, you can print `discord.__version__` after importing it to double check. Best practise is to use Python [venv](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) for packages like this.
Additionally, to make sure you are always accessing the correct pip, you can use `python -m pip`. This means you are always using pip for the same version you will invoke the script with later.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, I just needed to get it on 1.5.1 (:

Answer (score 0):

do this `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intent=discord.Intents.default() )` instead of `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intent=intents)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).