# discord.py on_member_join event not triggering

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to trigger the on_member_join event and it is not triggering when someone joins. I am trying to give someone a role on join too, but I pretty much know how to do that. I just do not understand why this event is not triggering on join. It was working but it stopped.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")



player = {}

# Events

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
     print("Bloody Admin is online:")
     await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("Prefix: !"))
     
     
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
     print("Joined")
    
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
     await member.create_dm()
     await member.send("I guess I watched you too hard, sorry to see you leave :(")
     

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
     await ctx.send(error)
```

I have even tried changing it to a client event

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

client = discord.Client()

player = {}

# Events

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
     print("Bloody Admin is online:")
     await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("Prefix: !"))
     
     
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
     print("Joined")
    
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
     await member.create_dm()
     await member.send("I guess I watched you too hard, sorry to see you leave :(")
     

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
     await ctx.send(error)
```

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the intents on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the Intents.

Make sure to turn on all the necessary ones in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) for your application.

**To implement them to your code you can use the following:**

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all() # Imports all the Intents
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="YourPrefix", intents=intents)
```

Comment: I get an error saying builtins.AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Intents'. I do have discord imported.

Comment: I assume you have an older discord.py version. Please update it to at least 1.5.1 or 1.6.0. There is actually a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64938766/discord-py-nameerror-name-intents-is-not-defined) explaining it pretty well.

Comment: Yea, I was running 1.4. Thank you so much.